# how to get ggplot in ipython

Tags: python, python-ggplot

I have a similar problem as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750572/unable-to-import-ggplot-in-python-3-5), however this fix didn't work for me. I am working in Spyder, Python 3.6 and want to run ggplot. After installing ggplot with pip, I am still unable to locate the module

```
import ggplot
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-1140326dc452>", line 1, in <module>
    import ggplot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ggplot'
```

EDIT:
I have also installed it in Anaconda Prompt with

```
pip install ggplot
```

and followed with

```
conda install ggplot
```

but have this error message

```
 PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - ggplot
```

Comment: edit: The `conda install ggplot` install worked with Jupyter. Forgoing Spyder. Any other solutions would still be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the Spyder environment, you need to install `ggplot` in a different manner, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539214/spyder-python-install-external-packages):

```
conda install ggplot
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like ggplot is in PyPi and I've already installed it via pip. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @Justin all the options are spelled out in that post.

Comment: @DerekBrown it's best to include the details of the post in the answer since the link may one day become invalid.